# If mining in a pool with claymore miner, can I turn off the miner and give my computer a break?

Tags: mining-pools

If I close the claymore mining window while it is mining in a pool, will I lose all the shares of work attributed to me up to that point?

I would like to give my computer a break for entertainment purposes at times and the miner does tend to slow down activities on my computer.

I'm using claymore dual miner and mining both Ethereum and Siacoin with nanopool.

This is an interesting experiment for me and the PC is not a dedicated mining rig.  It's more of a high powered gaming PC that I am using to learn a little bit more about cryptocurrency mining.  I suppose I am dipping my feet in the cryptocurrency mining waters so to speak.

Any information would be very helpful!

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the pool. Some pools use a pay-per-last-n-shares scheme (PPLNS) which means that only accounts that contributed shares in the last *n*-most-recent blocks are credited for work done. Thus, if no shares are found for a while after you stop mining, your shares may be "bumped off" the list of shares to be credited when a block is found. Statistically, over time, I think it's a wash (I haven't done the math), but any particular instance of gaming might lead to shares being "lost".

Answer (score 0):

Nope, whatever shares you sent to the pool is accepted by the pool and you can safely close the miner or bat file.